# Use defined variables from parent scope in a named template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to provide idiomatic access to a value defined in a template to a named template being `include`d. This much works:

```yaml
# values.yml
versions:
- 1.2.3.4
- 5.6.7.8
```

```yaml
# _helpers.tmpl
{{/*
Get the service path from the version string (passed as ".")
*/}}
{{- define "sample.servicePath" -}}
{{- $pat := "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.([0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+$" }}
{{- $version := . | trimAll "\"" }}
{{- if regexMatch $pat $version }}
{{- regexReplaceAll $pat $version "${1}" }}
{{- else }}
{{- printf "Can't extract service number from version string %s" . | fail -}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

```yaml
# sample.yml
{{- range $version := .Values.versions }}
{{- $servicePath := (include "sample.servicePath" $version) }}
# Here is the servicePath: {{ $servicePath }} which works
{{- end }}
```

But I imagined that this would also work:

```yaml
# _helpers.tmpl (further down in the file)

{{- define "sample.labels" -}}
servicePath: {{ $servicePath }}
{{- end }}
```

```yaml
# sample.yml
{{- range $version := .Values.versions }}
{{- $servicePath := (include "sample.servicePath" $version) }}
# Here is the servicePath: {{ $servicePath }} which still works
# but these labels: {{ include "sample.labels" . }} do not
{{- end }}
```

---

Ultimately I don't mind the implementation, I just need to be able to take a single list of values, range over them (to create multiple resources), and parse their value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language, and by extension Helm charts, doesn't have global variables or dynamic scopes; you can't do this in the way you're suggesting.  Each template invocation has its own scope, and the only things it can see are its single parameter `.` and any variables it declares locally.

However, Helm includes the [Sprig](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) extension library, which includes `list` and `dict` functions to create composite values.  You can use these to pass multiple values into a template:

```
{{- define "sample.labels" -}}
{{- $top := index . 0 -}}
{{- $servicePath := index . 1 -}}
app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ $top.Release.Name }}
servicePath: {{ $servicePath }}
{{ end -}}

{{- range $version := .Values.versions }}
{{- $servicePath := (include "sample.servicePath" $version) }}
{{- include "sample.labels" (list . $servicePath) }}
```

In the last line, we are invoking the template with a list of two parameters, the top-level Helm object (here as `.`) and the `$servicePath` local variable.  The top of the `sample.labels` template then unpacks that back into two local variables within its own template, and then uses those to generate a reference set of labels.